# I have difficulty understanding a phrase

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could somebody help me with this phrase?
what does it mean to "explain reasoning" ??!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> reasoning
>
> ˈriːz(ə)nɪŋ/
>
> noun
>
> the action of thinking about something in a logical, sensible way.
>
> "he explained the reasoning behind his decision at a media conference"

Simply put, it means to explain why you did or did not do something, generally you being asked the thought process behind it.

Comment: hmm thanks. I'll choose your answer as the most helpful. could you pls explain the meaning of this phrase, too? thanks
"offering empowering"

Comment: You'd be best to ask another question.